# Javascript creating methods - how to output

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some guidance on the simplest way to create an output     for the following code below. Just simple user output into an HTML document. Any guidance would be helpful. Also any guidance on how to use the join method so I could link two properties such as Lname and accNo also?

The idea would be to have user input box (for deposit/withdraw) and then using a button/buttons to complete the function and display the results.

```
<script>

function Account(fname, lname, accNo, amount) {   
this.fname = fname;
this.lname = lname;
this.accNo = accNo;
this.balance = amount;  
this.bankDeposit = deposit;  
this.bankWithdraw = withdraw; 

}

function deposit(amount) {  
this.balance += amount;  

}

function withdraw(amount) {
if (amount <= this.balance) {     
 this.balance -= amount;       
 }
if (amount > this.balance)  {
 alert("Declined");           
 }
}

function joinName() {


}


var P1 = new Account("Nathan", "Smith", "SA001", 500);
var P2 = new Account("John", "Smith", "SA002", 1500);



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this code currently work?.....dont think it will work

Comment: Yes I did some more work on the code to display the results and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have to point out that your methods wont work out as is. They need to be declared on your `Account` class prototype.

```
Account.prototype.deposit = function(amt) {
    ...
}
```

For the issue that you want to output html the absolute easiest method would be

```
Account.prototype.print = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this);
}
```

For the issue of combining properties you would do

```
Account.prototype.joinName = function() {
    return this.fname + ‘ ‘ + this.lname;
}
```

However, if you plan to use that joined name a lot I would just set it in the constructor.

```
this.joinedName = fname + ‘ ‘ + lname
```